# React native app crashes when release mode set in Xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, native

RN version: 0.32.0

Application runs OK when in debug mode but crashes when release mode set in Xcode. Error message is not clear:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

What should I do? How to diagnose this problem? Any solution?

[image: IOS app crashes]

Comment: both simulator and device

Comment: how can I run in release mode on xcode?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this behavior when a component was given twice the same prop. Like in

```
<Comp propname={"a"} propname={"b"}/>
```

This is just a possibility, though and I don't know if it is still happening in RN 0.32. Does it run when you run it in debug mode and debug in Chrome? This was how I found my issue.

Try identifying which component is responsible for it by removing them one by one.

Comment: Yes, when running in debug mode and debug in Chrome all is absolutely OK.

Comment: Ok, then I don't see any other solution than trying to remove your components one by one or trying to find the guilty commit if you have been using git.